# WSO2 ESB doesn't close connection

Tags: php, wsdl, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to get working WSO2 ESB 4.7.0 with PHP 5.4.9 SoapClient.
I've got a problem when I use SoapClient in WSDL mode with ESB echo service, that connection from ESB is not closed after sending WSDL. I'm able to reproduce this problem also with telnet as client.

```
$ telnet localhost 8280
```

HTTP 1.0 request:

```
GET /services/echo?wsdl HTTP/1.0
```

HTTP 1.0 response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml
Date: Mon, 29 Jul 2013 07:37:20 GMT
Connection: Close
```

And after response connection stays open (as would stay with "Connection: keep-alive" header).

Is this a bug or problem in configuration? Is anybody experiencing the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a similar issue. My LB is querying Version service but after a while the ESB stops responding and a bunch of connection timeouts are visible in the logs. I think the ESB is not releasing its connections. Must be some configuration option to specify to close connection or timeout after a period.

Comment: The problem was actually the connection to BAM not the initial incoming connection. Didn't get far enough to identtify the actual issue with BAM, just pulled the plug on it, too many bugs.